# fancyapps lightbox custom title format/template utilising data attributes from the anchor tag

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm stuck as where to begin on this. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have made a fiddle so you can see what I need. http://jsfiddle.net/RJajg/2/

I am using the [fancyapps lightbox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

And I am currently using the `type: 'outside'` setting. This means, when the lightbox is opened, the script gets the title attribute and places it below image inside a div.

The div has the class `.fancybox-title`

What I would like to achieve is adding more text into this div using data attributes from the image link.

So instead of it being just the title...

**Image 1**

I would like it to be like this...

**Image 1 | Download High-Res | Download Low-Res**

The Download high/low res words would in fact be anchor tags, using the data attributes from links. [Please see the fiddle for my mark up](http://jsfiddle.net/RJajg/2/).

Sorry I have not put much effort into my code but I'm stumped in where to begin or how the most efficient way of doing this. Any advice would be great thanks.

This my current code.

```
$('#gallery1 a').attr('rel','fancybox-thumb').fancybox({
    padding: '0',
    prevEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'none',
    closeBtn: false,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.9,
            css: {
                'background-color': '#000'
            }
        },
        buttons: {
            position: 'top'
        },
        thumbs: {
            width: 50,
            height: 50
        },
        title: {
            type: 'outside'
        }
    },
    closeClick: false
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `beforeShow` callback to set the `title` the way you want it like :

```
beforeShow: function () {
    var highRes = "<a href='" + $(this.element).data("download-high") + "'>Download High-Res</a>";
    var lowRes  = "<a href='" + $(this.element).data("download-low")  + "'>Download Low-Res</a>";
    this.title  = this.title ? this.title + " | " + highRes + " | " + lowRes : highRes + "|" + lowRes;
}
```

See your **[forked JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RJajg/4/)**

Comment: Dude this top notch. Thank you so much, works like a beaut. Have been wanting to do this for ages, and now I can use this for lots of other projects. ++1.